# Script for business hours javascript

Tags: javascript

I need script that will display "Open" & "Close" function on my site.

Script should display "OPEN" every day from Monday to Friday from 08:00am to 19:30pm

and for Saturday should display "OPEN" from 08:00am to 15:00pm  (else display CLOSED)

Sunday is CLOSED all day long.

*I try to manage this script but I was not able to achieve it:*

```
var Digital=new Date()
var hours=Digital.getHours()

if (hours>=08:00&&hours<=19:30) 
document.write('Open')
else if (hours>=19:31&&hours<=07:59) 
document.write('Close')
```

but i need addition for the days, this is just for time.

Comment: What timezone is the business in?

Comment: Script should use server time. timezone is (UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague

Comment: You can use `Digital.getDays()` to determine the day of the week and `Digital.getMinutes()` to get the minutes in the hour.

Comment: There is no syntax in JavaScript where `19:30` is valid. Read the documentation for [`getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) and you will realize that it returns a simple number—the hour number without minutes—not anything related to a time primitive.

Answer (score 2):

The `hours` variable will be an integer number, you need to compare it to a number, like this:

```
if (hours >= 8 && hours <= 19) 
    document.write('Open')
else if (hours >= 19 && hours <= 7) 
    document.write('Close')
```

When rewrite those methods, you will need to get and compare the minutes from the `Digital` variable too.

Comment: Well, you need to combine all your conditions in your `if` statement. Like `if ((day > 0 && day < 6) && (hours >= 8 && hours <= 19))`. For this, you will need to use the `.getDay()` method with your `Digital`variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the current date using `if` statements before checking the time. Your formatting was slightly off, as `digital.getHours()` returns a whole number rather than those formatted strings.

I also added a `setInterval` to update the status every minute, in case the page is left open for prolonged time.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6bwJ/1/

EDIT: Fixed a few bugs (namely typos). I also see you need localization for this. I made some changes to the top of the code which adjust for timezone, so it's always displaying information based on local time. There is one caveat though, and that is that it is currently hardcoded to include daylight savings. This means it will be inaccurate once DST switches.

Line 10:
`utc1Time=new Date(localTime.getTime() + (localTime.getTimezoneOffset() + 120) * 60000);`

That `+ 120` is adding 2 hours after converting client time to UTC time, which makes it UTC+1 and then adds the DST offset. You will need to add some way to check if DST is in effect, something along the lines of
`utc1Time.toString().match(/daylight/i)`
but I will leave that to you, as this is probably enough of a framework for you to build upon.

Hope this helped :D